# Python Optimization and Bizarre Output Responses

Tags: python, python-2.7, performance, performance-testing

I have two small issues regarding my code in Python 2.7, and I would like to see your input on these issues:

***Lesser Issue:*** So I've been testing a Python 2.7 script designed to output a degree heading after given a distance traveled around an ellipse. However, I need the program to run within 15 seconds to the full extent. Currently, the program outputs `31.1410000324 seconds for completion` which isn't terrible considering that it would be possible for me to divide the sample size into a little less than half.

***Main Issue:*** However, here is the other problem: at 3 specific points in the program, the result being output is not correct. One time it outputs `18.47700786`, and the other two output `37.90802974`. Why exactly is this happening? When I run all 3 of them normally, they all output the correct values, but at full speed, they appear to give strange values even though the values are consistent every time. I would like to know what you think.

Here is the script:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import time
a = 2; b = 1
Dx = lambda t: -a * np.sin(t)
Dy = lambda t: b * np.cos(t) 
encoderdistance = 0.00001
def func(x): return np.sqrt(Dx(x)**2 + Dy(x)**2)
time1 = time.time()
for i in range(2423):
    r_angle = (((180/np.pi) * np.arctan(((np.tan(minimize(lambda x: 
                 abs(quad(func, 0, x)[0] - encoderdistance), 1).x))*b)/a)))
    print r_angle[0]
    encoderdistance += 0.001
time2 = time.time()
print time2-time1, "seconds for completion"
```

And here is a graph of the output code: 
[image: Code Graph]

Comment: `encoderdistance += 0.001` causes floating point error. use `encoderdistance = 0.00001 + i * 0.001`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the quick response! That change did help to fix the second two downward spikes, but do you happen to know what is causing the first downward spike?

Comment: did you compute what I told you _before_ computing `r_angle` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, I placed the `encoderdistance = 0.00001 + i * 0.001` right after the initial `for` loop declaration before the `r_angle` calculation and removed both of the other `encoderdistance` calls. For reference, the new graph looks like this: https://gyazo.com/bce42f4954d2b69d83cfc9d3ec636a85